# How do I save the current state of an Android App?

Tags: android

I am new in Android Development. I am trying my hands on developing an alarm app. When I set the alarm, I use a TextView to show the time for which the alarm in set up(initially empty). But when I close or minimize the app and start it again the TextView is again empty. How to get rid of this?
I looked for its solution in android app development manual, but still couldn't find my way out.

Comment: You can search for Sqlite , SharedPreferences , Realm  etc..

Answer (score 0):

Particularly visiting developer.android.com will help you to get started with android development. Anyways you can either use any of the following to save your data:

- SharedPreferences
- Sqlite Database
- File (Pertaining to your app's location)

And when you are reopening your application you can retrieve the information from this methods.

Answer (score 0):

Saving data can be done easily with the SharedPreferences.

```
private final String SAVED_ALARM_TIME_KEY = "SavedAlarmTime"
private final String ALARM_PREFERENCES = "AlarmPreferences"

private void saveAlarmTime(Context context, long alarmTimestamp) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(ALARM_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putLong(SAVED_ALARM_TIME, alarmTimestamp);
    editor.commit();
}

private long getAlarmTime(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(ALARM_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     return sharedPref.getLong(SAVED_ALARM_TIME, 0); 
}
```

This is great for something like user settings in the application. But I imagine you will later want to add multiple alarms to your application. In this case it would be better if you used a database. It will provide you with more options to scale the implementation. For instance you wish to add a functionality for repeating alarms at certain days the database will come in very handy.

You can refer to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html